# Conectarse a un Servidor FTP desde una Maquina Virtual de Azure

Tags: azure

He creado una maquina virtual de gestión de recursos en la plataforma Azure y deseo conectarme a un servidor FTP remoto desde esa maquina virtual. Desde la VM puedo hacer Ping al servidor remoto pero no tengo acceso al puerto 21 (FTP) de ese servidor.

Se ha desactivado el Firewall de la Maquina Virtual y se ha creado la siguiente regla de salida. Pero aún así no hay conexión. Agradecería su apoyo.

[image: Ping From Azure Virtual Machine To Remote Server]

Comment: pero el FTP usa dos puertos, el 20 y 21   https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol   quizas debas abrir ambos

Comment: estas seguro que el servicio dentro de la VM esta bien configurado https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/12/12/setting-up-a-passive-ftp-server-in-windows-azure-vm/  lo planteo porque viendo los pasos si usas el IIS debe habilitarse para poder usarlo

Comment: He actualizado la imagen, como ven desde dentro de la Maquina Virtual (Resource Manager) puedo hacer ping al servidor que me quiero conectar, pero no hay acceso al puerto FTP de ese mismo servidor. Con una Maquina Virtual Clásica no había problemas pero con las nuevas MV's no se como se hace. Desde mi maquina local (No VM) puedo conectarme con normalidad.